# Is it possible open a new tab for drilldown report in Tableau after publishing it

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am working on a migration project from Cognos to Tableau. And I have created a dashboard with multiple reports and published them in Tableau Online. The issue is when I click on the drill-down reports then it's getting opened on the same page. Clients want that drill-down report to a new tab when clicked. Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the Main Report dashboard and name the duplicate something like Drill Down dashboard. On the Main Report dashboard, add a Filter Action. In the filter action configuration window, set the source to Main Report and the target to Drill Down. Then select the field to filter on (aka the name of the Dimension they want to drill down on). The filter action will actually do two things: 1. It will filter the target dashboard and 2. It will automatically navigate the user to the target dashboard.